# How to highlight max or min data?

Tags: tabulator

If I have an NxM grid of tabulator data that's numerical, I want to bold or highlight the cell that's maxmimum in a row or maximum in a column. I was wondering the best way to do this. It seems like I should pass in the row into a custom formatter, then iterate over the entries to get the max and return the format as bold or whatever.

This just seems a little calculation heavy as I have to iterate over all the cells for each row. Anyone have a better idea? Is there a built in way to get this? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: This is something you will have to roll yourself. For one thing  max in column may not be the same as max in a row so you are going to have to decide if they get different colors and what happens if they are the same in both axis for a given cell. Also whether this is automatic or produced on demand. Also is this for visible data only?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to handle this would be to identify the max/min values before importing them into the table by simply iterating over the array.

You could then set some flag properties in the row data(eg `minRow`, `maxRow`) that are set true if they apply, and then in the ***rowFormatter*** function use these to apply appropriate styling